# Is there a way to draw UML in Visio for Java?

Tags: java, uml, visio

I have Visio2007 and I really like it. However, it doesn't seem to have UML  model/datatypes for Java. Is there some template I can download for Java? Or should I just forget about Visio altogether and get an Elipse plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is a better option, IMHO. Further, I don't think UML Models should be specific to Java. I am not aware of, if there are any java-specific UML, around.

I found this while searching over the net. [UML Models: MS Visio 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HP012088141033.aspx).

Comment: As you suspect, UML is completely language independent.

Comment: UML is not language specific, but Visio uses "language specific" data types (C#/C++/VB) when you create classes for example. Maybe this was what tomato was referring to? Sorry for waking this old thread up =)

Answer (score 56):

I had the same question, but then I messed around with it until I figured it out. Now, bear with me; this is the first time I have ever posted a response to an answer. Since I figured it out I thought I should transfer my brain’s data into your brain (eww.. we’re interfacing).

Now to business... You can actually make up your own package and data types. What I did was I went to the `Model Explorer` tab on the left. Then, I right-clicked on `IDL Data Types`, and then I clicked `Duplicate` (since I didn’t want to make my own from scratch and it pretty much has what I want). It will then make a new package called "Package 1". Right-click on it and select `Rename`; I renamed mine to “Java Data Types” since that is what I am making, but you can name it “Underpants” if you want. Then, I opened my new package and right-clicked each data type, one at a time, and selected `Properties`. Then it will open up the `UML Property Editor`. From there, click on `Name`, then remove the word “idl” from inside the brackets, so “boolean(idl)” now says ”boolean()”.

Now, one other thing: There is no `int` data type, so you need to make one. It is pretty easy; just right-click on your newly created folder, click `New`, then click `Data Type`.  It should open the `UML Datatypes Properties` window. Now, click inside the `Name` tab, type in “int()”, then click `OK`. And you’re all done.

See, that wasn’t so bad. Heck if I can do it, you definitely should be able to do it. I hope this was understandable and helpful. If not, well I guess I have failed you and I should now fall on my sword to save my honor.

Comment: Great! Its incredible that no one has actually shared the Java data Type file, I've been serching it for hours and nothing. I did find  a diagram of the complete Java API XD. This is a real answer!

Comment: You can also click on the name of the method you want to change and hit F2 to quickly rename it.  Type over it, hit enter, and you're done.  Does anyone know of a way to get rid of the `<<datatype>>` stereotype that's added before the package name when you use one of these data types on a class diagram?

Comment: Never mind my question--I was trying to put data types onto my class diagram instead of classes using those data types.  That wasn't really my intention.

Answer (score 10):

There is a Visio UML template for Java at http://barzeenotes.blogspot.com/2014/11/java-and-javascript-support-for.html

Comment: @RexBarzee: Sorry, the account was deleted (probably due to inactivity).  Unfortunately there's no account left to merge.