# generate class diagram in visio

Tags: java, visio

Are there any tool or a trick that allows to generate class diagram in visio from java source code files?

I have managed to generate class diagrams in visual paradugm, however I have not found a way to export from visual paradigm into visio, so if there is a such conversion tool it is also approciated.

Comment: @java_developer, unfortunately I am forced to use visio

Comment: This may help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/814876/1130032

Comment: @java_developer, that is only collection of java types. That is helpful, but there is nothing about automatic generation :(