# Java code to UML Diagram

Tags: java, uml, visio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Is there some plugin for NetBeans or Eclipse that converts simple Java code to simple UML Diagram, which i could use in Microsoft Visio or some other UML editor.

I already tried ObjectAid, but it exports only images.

Comment: Did you try googling for it? Lots of results come up

Comment: @HunterMcMillen please be so kind and show which converts exactly to UML format, which supports visio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442099/is-there-a-way-to-draw-uml-in-visio-for-java

Comment: @TheStijn where there exactly the program?

Comment: [binarydoc](https://github.com/fuiny/binarydoc-docker-compose) is a **free** tool to generate UML diagrams from Java **bytecode** automatically. Here are some samples: [UML Sequence diagram for java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.getOutputStream](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/method?classfilelocation=java.net.abstractplainsocketimpl&seq=21&methodname=getOutputStream), [UML object diagram for java.net.DatagramSocket](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/classfile?classfilelocation=java.net.datagramsocket) .

Answer (score 0):

I use Enterprise Architect. It's a complete UML editor software, and you can import your java files and it makes for you the UML diagram.

Comment: isn't it a commercial software?

Comment: It is, but you can use trial version. More info: http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/